# setting vim buffer/window name

Tags: vim

I am creating a temporary buffer in vim which receives the output of a shell command.

The window/buffer gets the title: `[No Name]`

How can I manually set the name/title for this window/buffer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for `:file Somename` ?